# TypeError: obj is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sqlite

[image]

I have an object like:

```
{a:1,b:2,c:3}
```

I'm trying to build a sqlite update statement dynamically using:

```
function update_json_obj_into_table(tablename, obj) {

  const insertValues = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, k) => acc + (k + ' = ' + obj(k) + ','), "");
  console.log(insertValues);
  // db.run(`UPDATE ${tablename} SET ${insertValues} WHERE search_condition`);
};
```

based on https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-update/ I want insertValues to look like:

```
' a=1,b=2,c=3 '
```

which I want to insert into a sqlite table.

However I'm getting the error in the title. How can I fix this?

Comment: You’re trying to call “obj”, that’s what “obj(k)” does. Did you mean to use square brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the value at that key, you should use square brackets to access the property instead.

```
const insertValues = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, k) => acc + (k + ' = ' + obj[k] + ','), "");
```

You can use `Object.entries` as well.

```
const insertValues = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k,v]) => acc + (k + ' = ' + v + ','), "");
```